# iOS: The frame of tableViewCell changed when iPad switching to landscape

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

The effect I want is this, used storyboard with UITableViewController&UITableViewCell. No constraints in storyboard.
[image]

But in this controller made by pure code with UITableViewController&UITableViewCell, It looks narrow.
[image]

What makes it different?

Edit: In storyboard, The rootView of the controller is UITableView, so there is no constraint can be added to tableview. And if I only use pure code or storyboard, the effect is uniform, but I want to know how to switch the two interface?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using same xib for both iPhone and iPad. than i would suggest to use auto layout and also size class from interface builder.

Comment: i would suggest don't do it by coding. just add xib and it will solve rest of your issues for future implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use auto-layout on storyboard or xib.
But if cannot, then you have to programmatically resize/reload when orientation changed. Other wise table view wont auto re-layout cells according to table view frame size.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

open storyboard and preview it with iPad.

change wAny hAny to wRegular hRegular
[image: change wAny hAny to wRegular hRegular]

and rotate portrait to landscape iPad
if u have done ur constraints as per requirement it will surely auto rearrange.
[image]